# Angular js Injection Clarification

Tags: angularjs

I m new to Angular JS and I was going through few angular JS tutorials. The below one is one of the controller method. In the first case, $scope is included as part of the array string but in the second case $scope is injected in the function alone but both works fine. What is the difference and which approach has to be used?

```
 app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Test Success";
        }]);

        app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Test Success";
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

the first method is the recommended practice so the app does not break when (or if) minified. 
give this a read: https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification 
 and this: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 (scroll down to "A Note on Minification")

Answer (score 1):

First approach is preferable because while minification of javascript  function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Both notations are equal in the eyes of angular. I personally prefer and recommend the first one even.

Even though the above comments are correct, minification will break this, there is still [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which is built specifically for this: **Using the second notation it converts it to the array notation when minifying**